# Cancelling parent job without using explicit Job() object

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the following code, I create two jobs, then I cancel the parent job. I expect child jobs to be cancelled, however, child jobs are not cancelled they are still active. Why?

**Note**: I know this problem can be easily solved by creating a Job() object, then giving the job object to coroutine context, then cancelling the Job() object. My question is why the below code does not work? If I want to cancel parent job, must I use explicit parent parameter?

```
fun main() {

    // CoroutineScope
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    var child1 : Job? = null
    var child2 : Job? = null

    // Use
    val currentJob = coroutineScope.launch {
        child1 = coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(500)
        }
        child2 = coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(500)
        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(300L)

    currentJob.cancel()

    println("Job 1 state: ${child1?.status()}")
    println("Job 2 state: ${child2?.status()}")
    println("Parent job is active: ${coroutineScope.isActive}")
    println("Parent job is active: ${currentJob.isActive}")


    Thread.sleep(2000L)
}
```

Output :

```
Job 1 state: Active
Job 2 state: Active
Parent job is active: true
Parent job is active: false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`child1` and `child2` Jobs are not `currentJob`'s children. They are `coroutineScope` Job's children. We could say `currentJob`, `child1` and `child2` are "siblings". If you want to cancel them all then cancel `coroutineScope` instead:`coroutineScope.cancel()` . Or make them `currentJob`'s children and cancel `currentJob`:

```
val currentJob = coroutineScope.launch {
    child1 = launch {
        delay(500)
    }
    child2 = launch {
        delay(500)
    }
}

Thread.sleep(300L)

currentJob.cancel()
```

Comment: @oiyio the launch is called on inner passed CoroutineScope object, which registers those tasks into its job as a children.

Comment: oh my god. I realized it now... Ok your suggested code prints childs as cancelled as i expected. But coroutineScope.isActive returns still true. Why?

Comment: @oiyio Because you're cancelling only `currentJob` which will cancel `child1` and `child2`. Try this `coroutineScope.cancel()` to cancel the whole scope.